# How to make an alarm rings even with headphones

Tags: android, alarm

On the default alarm of my android, the alarm rings even when there is headphones (You can hear the music of the alarm). I have coded an alarm using Android Studio (using AlarmManager and a mediaPlayer when it rings) and I would like to know how can I have the same functionality on my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn on the speaker, this code has to be used:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn();
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```